How do I send a push notification via the OneSignal API?
When I try to send a push notification via the OneSignal API, I get this error: All included players are not subscribed. I can see my device subscribed on the OneSignal subscription records page, and when I send a notification via the OneSignal dashboard, it works. The device gets the push notification. But when I try to send a push notification via the API, it fails.
I'm sending a POST request to https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications.
I have the Basic Authorization header set, and that's working or I would be getting a different error.
I have also verified that the app ID is correct.
Here is my request body:
{
    "app_id": "[MY_APP_ID]",
    "included_segments": [
        "All Subscriptions"
    ],
    "target_channel": "push",
    "contents": {
        "en": "TEST"
    }
}

I have also tried Total Subscriptions and All in the included_segments array, but neither of those work either.
Initially, I was trying to send notifications to specific external IDs using include_alises instead of included_segments like so:
"include_aliases": {
     "external_id": [
         "[THE_EXTERNAL_ID]"
     ]
},

But that fails with the same error.
I've also tried targeting by subscription ID using include_subscription_ids, but that also fails with the same error.
What am I missing?

from your writeup
seems everything is fine
lets try this troubleshooting step
pick one subscrition_id and send a post request to the endpoint, see the response.

Are you using the correct API key? For sending notifications, you should be using the "REST API Key" and not the "API Key" from OneSignal dashboard

Well, this is embarrassing. Thank you @xtcntr. I had noticed before that the API key I've been using doesn't match the rest API key in my dashboard, and trying that key  returned an error. That lead me to realize the app_id in my request didn't match either for some reason. My best guess is that I was testing with a different account or setup previously, didn't change the api key and app_id when I changed the OneSignal app, and forgot about it months ago. The bounty is still active, so if you want to add an answer about that, go for it.

so the question got resolved in the comments itself, still adding the answer for.. reasons.
the solution:
OneSignal uses the "REST API Key" for notifications, not the "API Key". Mixing them up would cause something like this to happen

I have done some research and found that user will get error like All included players are not subscribed due to below reasons:

May be the APP_ID is incorrect.
May be the API_KEY is incorrect.
You have no users subscribed.

Please ensure above things first.
You can check subscriptions from OneSignal -> Audience -> Segments tab.
If you already have user subscribed than check their subscription status OneSignal -> Audience -> Users tab.
Also you can check below some of documentations blog and other research regarding this:
https://onesignal.com/blog/how-to-send-push-notifications-with-the-onesignal-rest-api/
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/896
https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/56264/onesignal-plugin-sample-no-players-subscribed/
please check and try if you already haven't.
If you want to check your API is working or not than you can simple try your API in postman with a single player/user id who is already subscribed and visible in one signal subscribed users list.
